# Tomcat virtual host with websocket "http_upgrade" configuration

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

I have a java application with web socket running on 8080 port on my server through tomcat like http://localhost:8080/application. But i am facing problem connecting to web socket i had it working fine with nginx with below code and want similar configuration for tomcat. Please keep in mind there is no httpd file in my configuration i am just using tomcat server so i want configuration in server.xml

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ''      close;
       }
server {

        listen 80;
        server_name _;


        location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        }
        location /websocket-stomp/  {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
                     } 
        }
```